# What does findOne() return exactly in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

you pass in a callback:

```
function(err, found) {

if(err) 
// checks to see if there was an error

else if (found)
// checks if the document exists

}
```

to execute the query "immediately". Is this the correct way to check if the document exists? How can I tell if the document exists or not? How can I tell if there was an error executing the query (suppose the connection was lost before the database could return the results). I'm just a little confused and some clarification would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have will work fine.

If there was an error, you will want to throw the error.

If the query returned a document, found will default to true.

You can then proceed to use the found object inside your second if statement.

To see if the query was successful but no user was found:

```
function(err, found) {

    if(err){
        throw err;
    }

    if(found){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(found));
    }else{
        console.log('The query was successful, but nothing was found');
    }
}
```

Comment: what if the query didn't return a document? Will it default to false? null?

Comment: You can catch that with an else statement after your if (found). I'll show you in my answer.